# Flattr API Call for Discoverable URLs

Tags: api, url, flattr

Do you know how to do an API Call for Discoverable URLs? Can I just do something like:

```
http://flattr.com/submit/auto?url='PUT_URL_HERE'
```

without any aditional data like user_id etc.?

Comment: I don't seem to understand really what you want to do. But I will try to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a endpoint in the Flattr API to lookup information about a URL. The endpoint is https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/lookup. You do a GET request with a added `url` parameter containing the URL you want to know more about.

Example:

Request>

`GET /rest/v2/things/lookup?url=http://smgt.me`

Response>

`HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect

Location: https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things/435836

{"message":"found","location":"https:\/\/api.flattr.com\/rest\/v2\/things\/435836"}`

In the lookup resource you can also find information about autosubmit URL. More information about [lookup resource in the dev docs](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/#check-if-a-thing-exists). If you on the otherhand want to try to Flattr a URL (both a regular URL and a autosubmit URL) you can have a look at the [flattr resource docs](http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-url). More information about [autosubmit URLs](http://developers.flattr.net/auto-submit/) is also available over at the developer docs.